# Use WHERE and REGEX in mysql statement

Tags: mysql, regex

I am new to this.
I want to select rows with 1) `content = 'cc'` 2) `id = 2` 3) `type` should be something like `/^ch[1-8]{1,1}l[1-8]{1,1}$/i`

Problem is that i don't know how to write it in mysql statement. It should be easy but i am new to this.

Comment: ` column RLIKE regex` is the where clause you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can combine all the conditions into one SELECT statement like this:

```
SELECT * FROM usertable WHERE content = 'cc' AND id = 2 AND type REGEXP '^ch[1-8]l[1-8]$';
```

Here is [an article](http://www.hackingwithphp.com/9/3/13/multiple-where-conditions) describing how to use multiple WHERE conditions.